# I want to type initials in a cell and have it generate the first name in a different cell, from a custom list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've just started last week at a job that uses Excel for various things, largely simple tasks. I'm trying to generate a certified mailing label template for some of the clerical ladies, but they are terrible about remembering to scroll down to the next page, so my goal is to make it so that they can write initials at the top of the page where they input data/address changes, and it will generate the name of whose those initials are in the PostScript of the mailer label, without having to scroll down.

I have found lots of information on changing colors and formulas but everything seems to be exclusively for numbers for that kind of thing so I'm trying to understand how I can make this work.

I read a little bit about IF functions but I haven't figured out how I would make it work with that, plus even if it's nested we have more than seven workers and I guess it'll only Nest seven functions in the IF formula, so I guess that would have limited availability anyway!

This is kind of what I'm thinking of, which is why I thought the IF function should work but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
If B2 is            Then D42 is
CK                   Chris
CW                   Christina
CT                   Christine
RW                   Rachel
```

Comment: Take a look at VLOOKUP.  It does exactly this.  Just create a lookup table like what's in your example, then use VLOOKUP to pick the name based on the entered initials.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! Before I get lost for a while, because I tend to do that when I have my attention directed elsewhere, do you happen to know if this is something that I can add to the worksheet itself, so that if it's opened on a different computer than mine it will still be valid? I know some of the things that I was looking at were add-ons that I couldn't guarantee would be on the computer is of the ladies opening it is so I'm trying to figure that out too.

Comment: VLOOKUP is a built-in function in all versions of Excel.  If you create a spreadsheet that has formulas using this function and then give the spreadsheet to other users, they will be able to use it on their computers.

Comment: Does the table exist in file?Can you provide a sample file about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through this step by step

Create a new sheet, or use an existing blank sheet and let's call it `Names`.

[image: Additional Sheet called names]

In this sheet let's create your custom list

[image: Custom List]

Now, in the sheet you wish to carry out the task, let's say we are putting the initials into cell `A1`, you would select the cell where you want the first name to be and type in the following formula.

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Names!A:B,2,FALSE)`

[image: image of the result]

> **NOTE:**
>
> I have set ***range_lookup*** (the last part of the VLOOKUP formula) to FALSE because if it is set to TRUE or left out, the first column of your custom list needs to be sorted alphabetically or numerically. If the first column isn't sorted, the return value might be something you don't expect.

Setting `range_lookup` to FALSE allows the list to be unsorted, and you can add names and initials to the bottom without worrying about alphabetical or numberical sorting.